# React + Formik - how to pass in new values and set form as dirty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a Formik form in my React app and I have a specific scenario I can't seem to find a workaround for:

I have a toggle outside of my custom form component that essentially "sets everything in the form to false". My current solution is when that gets toggled, I update the props I'm passing to form component, and re-rendering:

In my Form component:

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState(props.initialState);

useEffect(() => {
  setInitialState(props.initialState);
}, [props.initialState]);

...
...

<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialState={initialState}
  ...
/>
```

This *does* correctly update my form with the new values, but it *doesn't* set the form to be `dirty`. I have logic in my form component based on whether it is dirty, and in this scenario I want the form to be considered dirty. I first tried to set each field to be `touched` or include each one in `initialTouched`. However, `dirty` is computed comparing current values to `initialState`, not whether fields have been touched, so my form here is considered "pristine" because it is literally the same as my (new) initial state.

What I'm looking for is either:

- A way to pass in these new values as something other than `initialState` (ie somehow imperatively set values from outside `<Formik />`) that would cause `dirty` to be computed as true
- A way to force my form to be dirty (it's a read-only property, but if there is another way to mimic it and force it to be true)

Answer (score 2):

```js
       onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
          setSubmitting(true);
          setTimeout(async () => {
            console.log(values);

            // it will set formik.isDirty to false
            // it will also keep new values
            resetForm({ values });  

          }, 100);
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [onReset](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#onreset-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void) property? That should allow you to pass values from any source you want.

Comment: Ah thanks, but it seems to be impossible (by design) - since formik handles its state internally there really isn't a way to imperatively change it from the outside. I ended up just moving my toggle functionality into the form and it works!